# ASP MVC application design needing to access multiple databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to design an .NET MVC application and the application needs to access data from multiple databases. I the only way to do the low level database I/O is by calling MS SQL stored procedures. What I think is the best way to go is to develop the data layer using a combination of WCF as the lowest level calling the actual stored procedures. From there I feel that an Entity Framework layer be setup to be used for the actual MVC design. Can anyone give me a few I ideas to the best way for a successful design?

Comment: WCF is a transport mechanism, not a data access layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going to use entity framework so I think you can go with multiple data access layer.

- DALDatabase1
- DALDatabase2

Both these database can have their own repositories. This will be the cleaner approach.

You use one layer as well but that will going to be messy in future.

Comment: Please excuse me my subject question used MVC.Yes I understand that MVC is the transport mechanism but I just wanted to claify that I was not going to use a .NET ASP design calling a DAL layer using standard ADO.

Comment: Now, I have read several articles about doing all of the data access using a Entity Framework design with multiple DAL implentations. Mine is very problematic. I have many databases that all applications share and poor relational design. What I am hoping to do is find out the best way have a WCF project make the very complex stored procedure calls then having a single entity fromework DAL loading it's entities by calling the WCF endpoint requests. I have looked at a few articles about doing this and think this might be the best way to go. I just want to make sure I do it right, if that's best.

Comment: I just found about a helper that I thought would do the job but doesn't. It is called Ninject. This allows you to call different databases from within the same data access module. My problem is that the stored procedures I am creating require database joins within the same stored procedure. After reading about Ninject I still think I'm stuck?

Comment: Naveen yours is the best way. Using multiple data access layers and getting away from complex store procedures is the way to go. Because I'm not using the stored procedures I am going to try to convert them to Linq. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. You could also accept my answer if it solves your problem